# Как сделать событие клик по всем элементам при нажатии на определённую кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p class='mainclick'></p>
<p class='click'>2</p>
<p class='click'>3</p>
<p class='click'>4</p>
<p class='click'>5</p>
<p class='click'>6</p>
<p class='click'>7</p>
```

имеются теги p с классом click

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.click')
    nodes.forEach( el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nodes.forEach( el => { el.click() })
        })
    })
```

Данный скрипт позволяет нажать на все теги с классом click при нажатии на любой из них

Подскажите как можно переписать данный скрипт, чтобы событие клика по всем тегам с классом клик осуществлялось только при нажатии на  `<p class='mainclick'></p>`?
Спасибо

Comment: А какой смысл создавать столько _EventListener_ для каждого отдельного элемента, если можно создать один для родительского элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так например

```js
const mainClick = document.querySelector('.mainclick');
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.click');
mainClick.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (node of nodes) {
    node.click();
  }
})
```

```html
<p class='mainclick'>Click</p>
<p class='click'>2</p>
<p class='click'>3</p>
<p class='click'>4</p>
<p class='click'>5</p>
<p class='click'>6</p>
<p class='click'>7</p>
```